# Obtaining a Lite Coin Spot Price using Coinbase Java API V1.10.0

Tags: java, coinbase-api

Currently using Coinbase Java API 1.10.0 to obtain Litecoin / Euro spot price. This is proving tricky, as it would seem that the API defaults to Bitcoin and provides no Litecoin option. This code:

```
BigDecimal bd2 = cb.getSpotPrice(CurrencyUnit.EUR).getAmountMajor();
```

produces a Euro value for Bitcoin, but an attempt to modify to:

```
BigDecimal bd2 = cb.getSpotPrice(CurrencyPair.LTC_EUR).getAmountMajor();
```

fails as the `getSpotPrice()` method does not take the `CurrencyPair.LTC_EUR` argument. The Python implementation will work with this, but it looks like the Java API does not have this capability. Not good if you have to work this in Java!
Is there any way within the Java API that a Litcoin quote can be obtained?

Comment: Is there a `CurrencyUnit.LTC_EUR` instead of `CurrencyPair.LTC_EUR`?  I suspect that `getSpotPrice()` expects `CurrencyUnit`s but you are trying to feed it a `CurrencyPair`.

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? can you include the exception in your question? You should look at the 'getSpotPrice()' method definition and see what kind of value it is expecting.  I think the @zero298 is probably right

Comment: Looking at the source code, it looks like that library only registers `BTC`.  I may be incorrect though.  Take a look at this line right [here](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-java/blob/082d09fb492cc47f16f1204b2982cd3dd99eaf53/src/main/java/com/coinbase/api/CoinbaseImpl.java#L127).  I don't quite understand what it's talking about with respect to Android.

Comment: You may need to make your own `LTC_EUR` using `registerCurrency` before trying to use it.  See [joda's documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/apidocs/org/joda/money/CurrencyUnit.html#registerCurrency-java.lang.String-int-int-java.util.List-).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try adding LTC as a currency via the registerCurrency method. I think the issue may be that the API has been  neglected and now requires some updates to cater for the new cryptos,